# Xml sorting with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to sort XML based on `JobDate` using XSLT.

For example, with a given *test.xml*:

```
<ROOT>
 <Employees>
     <EmployeName JobDate="1-jan-2015 to 1-jan-2016">
        <Name>A</Name>
     </EmployeName>
     <EmployeName1 JobDate="2-nov-2014 to 5-may-2015">
       <Name>B</Name>
     </EmployeName1>
  </Employees>
</Root>
```

XSLT code:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/Employees">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="descending"/>
         <xsl:if test="fn:exists(EmployeName1)">
         <fo:table>
            <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
            <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
               <xsl:for-each select="EmployeName1">
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="8" padding="-1" display-align="center">                                                                            <fo:block-container overflow="hidden">                                                      <fo:block text-align="left">                                                                                <fo:inline color="black" font-family="Tondo Corp" font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold">                                                                           <xsl:text>EmployeName1 - </xsl:text>                                                        </fo:inline>                                <xsl:for-each select="@JobDate">                                        <altova:inline-container-substitute color="black" font-family="Tondo Corp" font-size="9pt">                                         <fo:inline>                                                 <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>                  </fo:inline>                                                            </altova:inline-container-substitute>                                                                   </xsl:for-each>         </fo:block>                                                             </fo:block-container>                                                                           </fo:table-cell>
                 </fo:table-row>
                 <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table>
                       <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
                      <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
                      <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
                         <xsl:for-each select="Name">
                           <fo:table-row>
                             <fo:table-cell padding="0" display-align="center" altova:is-body-cell="true">                                                                                              <fo:block-container overflow="hidden"><fo:block text-align="left">                                          <xsl:for-each select="upper-case(Name)">                                                                                                                <altova:inline-container-substitute color="red" font-family="Tondo Corp" font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold" margin-bottom="0mm" margin-top="0mm" padding-bottom="0mm" padding-top="0mm">                                                            <xsl:choose>                                                                    <xsl:when test=". instance of element() or . instance of document-node()">                                                                              <xsl:apply-templates/>                                                  </xsl:when>         <xsl:otherwise>                                                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>                                                      </xsl:otherwise>                                                                </xsl:choose>                                                           </altova:inline-container-substitute>                                   </xsl:for-each>                                                 </fo:block></fo:block-container>                                    </fo:table-cell
                           </fo:table-row>
                         </xsl:for-each>
                      </fo:table>
                    </fo:table>
                 </fo:table-row>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
         </fo:table>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="fn:exists(EmployeName)">
         <fo:table>
            <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
            <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
               <xsl:for-each select="EmployeName1">
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="8" padding="-1" display-align="center">                                                                            <fo:block-container overflow="hidden">                                                  <fo:block text-align="left">                                                                                <fo:inline color="black" font-family="Tondo Corp" font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold">                                                                           <xsl:text>EmployeName - </xsl:text>                                                         </fo:inline>                                                                                                <xsl:for-each select="@JobDate">                                                <altova:inline-container-substitute color="black" font-family="Tondo Corp" font-size="9pt">                 <fo:inline>                                                                         <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>  </fo:inline>                                                                                    </altova:inline-container-substitute>                                                   </xsl:for-each>                             </fo:block>                                         
</fo:block-container>                       
</fo:table-cell>
                 </fo:table-row>
                 <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table>
                       <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
                      <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
                      <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
                         <xsl:for-each select="Name">
                           <fo:table-row>
                             <fo:table-cell padding="0" display-align="center" altova:is-body-cell="true">                      
<fo:block-container overflow="hidden">                                      <fo:block text-align="left">                                            <xsl:for-each select="upper-case(Name)">                                    <altova:inline-container-substitute color="red" font-family="Tondo Corp" font-size="7pt" font-weight="bold" margin-bottom="0mm" margin-top="0mm" padding-bottom="0mm" padding-top="0mm">                                        <xsl:choose>                                                                        <xsl:when test=". instance of element() or . instance of document-node()">                                                                              <xsl:apply-templates/>                                                  
</xsl:when>     <xsl:otherwise>                                                                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>                                                      </xsl:otherwise>                                                                </xsl:choose>                                                           </altova:inline-container-substitute>                                   </xsl:for-each>                                                 
</fo:block>                                                 
</fo:block-container>                                       
</fo:table-cell
                           </fo:table-row>
                         </xsl:for-each>
                      </fo:table>
                    </fo:table>
                 </fo:table-row>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
         </fo:table>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I need help to sort this xml, thanks in advance.

Comment: First you have to convert the dates to something sortable, i.e. formatted YYYYMMDD.  Then you have to decide what "sorted" means for date ranges that overlap.  Do you sort on the start date or the end date?

Comment: add your expected output XML

Comment: Is your input XML entirely accurate? The second Employee has an `id` attribute with the date, and not a `JobDate` attribute. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I want to sort starting date and sorry for second employee id is a JobDate. i am interested to know, how to sort this xml when element name is different like first one is <EmployeName> and second is <EmployeName1>. i  all ready try with <xsl:for-each select="./*">
               <xsl:sort select="./@JobDate" order="ascending"/>Once again thanks for help

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/Employees">
  <xsl:for-each select="./*"> <xsl:sort select="./@JobDate" order="ascending"/>
     <fo:table>
        Here i am displaying xml data  in table format
     </fo:table>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>    But its not working for me

Comment: Can you edit your question to fix the XML, and also to show the latest XSLT you are using, as it is hard to follow code in comments? Also, can you give more detail as to how it is "not working"? Are you getting an error, for example? Editing your question to show your expected output, and the output you are actually getting, would help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this in XSLT 1.0, you will need to do some fairly tricksy string manipulation, as you need to sort first, by year, then by month and then by day. The month is the trickiest, as you actually need to sort by the month number, not by name.

Here is a way you can do it though

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="years" select="'jan-feb-mar-apr-may-jun-jul-aug-sep-oct-nov-dec'" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table> 
        <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/Employees"> 
            <xsl:for-each select="*"> 
                <xsl:sort select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-before(@JobDate, ' '), '-'), '-')" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($years, lower-case(substring-before(substring-after(@JobDate, '-'), '-'))))" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="substring-before(@JobDate, '-')" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                <row>
                    <cell><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></cell>
                    <cell><xsl:value-of select="@JobDate" /></cell>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this input....

```
<ROOT>
 <Employees>
     <EmployeName JobDate="1-nov-2014 to 1-jan-2016">
        <Name>B</Name>
     </EmployeName>
     <EmployeName1 JobDate="1-nov-2015 to 5-may-2016">
       <Name>C</Name>
     </EmployeName1>
     <EmployeName2 JobDate="2-aug-2014 to 5-may-2015">
       <Name>A</Name>
     </EmployeName2>
  </Employees>
</ROOT>
```

The following is output

```
<table>
   <row>
      <cell>A</cell>
      <cell>2-aug-2014 to 5-may-2015</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>B</cell>
      <cell>1-nov-2014 to 1-jan-2016</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>C</cell>
      <cell>1-nov-2015 to 5-may-2016</cell>
   </row>
</table>
```

Do note this assumes the months are always lower case

Comment: Thanks Tim, but still its not sorting based on date.

Comment: I've made an amendment to my answer. See http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQgp to see it in action.